# Configure Angular UI Button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a angular-ui button that looks like this:

```
<button uib-btn-checkbox ng-model="sortReverse" class="btn btn-default" ng-init="sortReverse=true"> <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-sort-asc': sortReverse===true,'fa-sort-desc': sortReverse===false}"></i></button>
```

This works fine.

Every time the model turns true, the `active` class is applied to the element. In the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons) they say you can change the class name of the checked button. Here is the quote:

> Default settings `uibButtonConfig`
>
> `activeClass` (Default: `active`) -
>   Class to apply to the checked buttons.

But i do not understand how exactly this should be done, could not find examples anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your controller you can inject `uibButtonConfig` and set the classes to be applied for active button.

Example

```
.controller('UibButtonsController', ['uibButtonConfig', function(buttonConfig) {
  buttonConfig.activeClass = 'your-class-name';
}])
```

[**See Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mF7Kw7Nmpd3VVlFtmL4a?p=preview)

I have set active class `grey` that changes the background of active button to grey color.

Comment: Thx. My goal was to remove the active class, so I tried with `active-class=""` and `active-class="''"`, but this did not work out. The button element still gets the active class when toggling to true.

Comment: @Hinrich Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Setting the class as attribute on the element (`active-class="someclass"`) like in your first guess would have seemed more natural to me. I wonder why they force you to inject the config instead . Also this config affects the whole controller. If i wanted different classes on different buttons, i would need to create multiple controllers for every case, right? This could be a pain.